# Multiple AngularJS apps in a single page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have the following 2 apps in a single page

#### Navbar Module

Located in the navbar of the page. Is included in every page of the application via the master layout file (im using laravel). Contains Search functionality + Navbar functions like (logout, login) etc.

#### Posts Module

Displayed only in the Dashboard page of the applications. Basically loads and display posts from backend.

Currently both are two seperate apps and i load them using `angular.bootstrap`. Both of the apps need to use a common service, `UserService`. Which basically loads the logged in user details. This is part of a different module, say `myapp.utils`. This service will parse data from html tags and build a User object ready for the consumers (Posts & Navbar apps). But when i inject the service into both apps, the User object is build twice. Which is what i don't want. For the below code, i could see the log printed twice in console.

```
.factory('UserService', function(){
    console.log("Initing UserService");

    return {
        'User':...
    }
})
```

I can't merge both app into a single bigger module, just because both modules are declared in two different blade templates (server view files).

Kindly suggest an alternate strategy.

Comment: Why not create a third module that depends on the two modules?  Then have it route messages between the two.  That way you can have one module telling the other that it's using a service, don't react.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a singleton using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and then use the `.factory()` method to either create the single instance or return it in your shared module, you will limit the number of times it gets instantiated to just one.

This singleton instance can use Angular services, but the tricky part would be if you needed a service that is unique per Angular app. Such as `$rootScope` or `$rootElement`. You would probably have to pass them in to the function on the shared service that used it, which would be painful.

Here is my little demo that hopefully simulates your scenario nicely.

```js
var timesInstantiated = 0;

(function() {
  var singletonInstance = null;

  function MyService($filter) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
    console.log('Creating sharedSvc instance');
    timesInstantiated++;
  }

  MyService.prototype.strikeItRich = function() {
    return "I just found " + this.$filter('currency')(20, '$');
  };

  angular.module('shared', [])
    .factory('sharedSvc', function($filter) {
      if (!singletonInstance) {
        singletonInstance = new MyService($filter);
      }
      return singletonInstance;
    });
})();


var topApp = angular.module('topApp', ['shared'])
  .run(function($rootScope, sharedSvc) {
    $rootScope.topMessage = "I'm on top of the DOM (hey oh)";
    $rootScope.sharedMessage = sharedSvc.strikeItRich();
  });

var bottomApp = angular.module('bottomApp', ['shared'])
  .run(function($rootScope, sharedSvc) {
    $rootScope.bottomMessage = "Bottom's up! (Who switched gravity?!)";
    $rootScope.sharedMessage = sharedSvc.strikeItRich();
  });


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // bootstrap both modules
  console.log('Bootstrappin\'...');
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('top-app'), ['topApp']);
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('bottom-app'), ['bottomApp']);

  document.getElementById('times-instantiated').textContent = timesInstantiated;
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-app">
  <h3>Top App</h3>
  <p>Top Message: {{topMessage}}</p>
  <p>Shared Message: {{sharedMessage}}</p>
</div>
<div id="bottom-app">
  <h3>Bottom App</h3>
  <p>Bottom Message: {{bottomMessage}}</p>
  <p>Shared Message: {{sharedMessage}}</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<p>Times shared service instantiated: <span id="times-instantiated">?</span></p>
```